# Displaying some tabular data, but it has a dynamic layout. Div? Table?

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I have a requirement to display some data to a user.

The data is displayed as "Label: InputForLabel" and will have two columns. It looks like this:

[image]

I started by just using a table with four columns for every row. Each column has a width of 25% and the table has a width of 100% -- so this gives the display we see above.

```
.ContentTable {
    width: 100%;
}

.ContentTable tr {
    height: 18px;
}

.ContentTable tr td{
    width: 25%;
}
```

Now, I have an additional requirement to be able to dynamically remove a given item and its label. If I just hide the item/label - a gap would be left in the table. I'm hoping to always have 2 item/labels displayed per row and have everything just sort of collapse upwards as item/labels are hidden.

Does this sound like something divs would be able to do more easily? Or is there a way to tell a table object "Always have this many columns for each row. If a column is hidden, pull up the first column from the next row and slide everything forward"?

Comment: Do you also generate the markup? If so, this is not really tabular data, more like a list, and hence should be treated as one. If you control the markup, you can probably dynamically populate the columns (each can be within a container, such as a `div`) using JS as items are displayed or hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in having one big table, so even if you stay with a markup made of tables, you should split it into two columns (which will makes your problem about showing/hiding some rows of one of the column disappear :o).

Then, we could ask the question weither or not the table layout is suited when you have split the content into two columns : I think MasterAM is right and you should give it a try using `ul` for this kind of layout (and hiding just an element of a list is still as easy as it is with a row in a table)

Comment: Oh man. Very wise! It's a late Friday, but you are completely correct in your realization that if I use two tables I do not have the issue... and then if I split into two tables.. why use any tables at all. I will look into it. :)